# Optimization with Big O notation

Tags: probability, optimization, asymptotics

Say I'm trying to optimize $f(t)=e^{O(t^2 \sigma^2)-t\lambda \sigma}$ with respect to $O(t^2\sigma^2)$ when $t\to 0$. Moreover, I assume $t \in [0,1]$, $f\in [0,1]$, and $\sigma,\lambda>0$. I'm trying to show that upon optimizing I get
$$\max_{t \in [0,1]}f(t) = C\max \{e^{-c\lambda^2},e^{-c\lambda \sigma}\},$$
for some $C,c>0$. I admit I'm not too familiar with Big O notation, hence why I'm trying to understand this. Since the big O notation only provides information when $t$ gets close to $0$, what I've done is assuming $t<t_0$ for some $t_0$,
$$e^{O(t^2\sigma^2)-t\lambda \sigma}\leq e^{c_0 t^2\sigma^2 -t\lambda \sigma},$$
for some $c_0>0$.
The derivative of the right hand side is $0$ when $t=\frac{\lambda}{2\sigma c_0}$ but I think this is a minimum, so plugging this back in I get
$$e^{c_0 t^2\sigma^2 -t\lambda \sigma}\geq e^{-\frac{\lambda^2}{4c_0}}.$$
Which isn't quite what I'm looking for.

This is from https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/254a-notes-1-concentration-of-measure/ in the proof of the Chernoff bound.

Comment: Your notation makes little to no sense. Note that $O(\cdot)$ depends on a point where the bounding is happening. For example, to say that "$f(x) = O(x^2)$ at infinity" means that $f(x) \leq c x^2$ for all $x > A$ (for some $A$ that depends on $f$). To say that "$f(x) = O(x^2)$" has no meaning. You are doing this, and also keeping $t \in [0, 1].$ So, it is really not clear what your assumptions are.

Comment: Thanks, I've made the edit. I should've been more clear, was just following Tao's notation in which he wrote the same thing.

Comment: For every $c \geq 0,$ $1 \leq e^{c t^2 \lambda^2 } \leq e^{c \lambda^2}$ and then you get a trivial bound for $f$ this way. Again, you probably have an interesting question but as of yet, it is not quite clear. good luck though.

Comment: @William M. Let me share that the big-$O$ notation makes sense not for a point, but, generally, for a set. Simply the most well-known and very common case is when this set is a system of neighborhoods of a certain limit point. See the general definition at N G De Bruijn - Asymptotic methods in analysis-NORTH HOLLAND PUBLISHING, 1961, page 4. Thus OP can apply the notation to the segment as well.